# Wireless problems ubuntu 12.04 edubuntu

Tags: wireless, software-recommendation, internet, laptop, distro-recommendation

I tried to go from normal ubuntu 12.04 to edubuntu 12.04 because I had some problems with my wireless connection. The problem still occurs in edubuntu, the wifi symbol says that I got signal but when I go on the internet, suddenly after a random period of time I cant download/browse anymore but the wifi symbol still says that I got a signal.

This problem also occured when I had Windows XP with SP3 installed, I thought It was a case of bad drivers but I never really found the solution.

I´m kind of fed up ATM because for the last few days I´ve been trying all I can to get my computer to work again under a different OS than Windows, so far unsuccesfull.

I hope someone can help me so I finally will be able to use my laptop ( dell latitude d620) again.

Thanks in Advance!

Wireless info:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub [8086:27a0] (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a2] (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a6] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 [8086:27d0] (rev 01)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 [8086:27d4] (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:27c8] (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:27c9] (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:27ca] (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:27cb] (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:27cc] (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:27b9] (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:27c4] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller [8086:27da] (rev 01)
03:01.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: O2 Micro, Inc. OZ601/6912/711E0 CardBus/SmartCardBus Controller [1217:6972] (rev 40)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5752 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1600] (rev 02)
```

LSUSB:

```
LSUSB:Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0846:9001 NetGear, Inc. WN111(v2) RangeMax Next Wireless [Atheros AR9170+AR9101]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 413c:a005 Dell Computer Corp. Internal 2.0 Hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b97:7761 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 1.1 Hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0b97:7762 O2 Micro, Inc. Oz776 SmartCard Reader
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details about your wireless card. Open a terminal and run and post: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: I don't see a wireless device in lspci. May we see: lsusb

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem occurs with two different versions of Ubuntu and also with Windows XP, I suspect the router setup. How is the wireless configured? WPA2 and what encryption? TKIP or AES? AES is preferred. If possible, do not use mixed-mode WPA and WPA2. Is it capable of N speeds? Have you tried resetting the wireless to B and G only? Is it capable of both 2.4 Ghz and 5 Ghz bands? Have you tried disabling the 5 Ghz band?

Comment: I haven´t tried that but I´m also suspecting the router, my sister has the same problem. I will try it out and post my findings!